# r :Error: could not find function -User defined

Tags: r

I am trying to run the below simple function in R studio

```
    a<-testfunc15(state,outcome)
           {

            st<-state
            out<-outcome 
             print(st)
             tempdff<-healthcareoutcome[healthcareoutcome$State==st,]
             tempdff 

              }
```

When i copy and paste of the R prompt of the R studio ,i get an error :

```
    Error: could not find function "testfunc15"
     > {
      + 
      + st<-state
      + out<-outcome 
      + print(st)
      + tempdff<-healthcareoutcome[healthcareoutcome$State==st,]
      + tempdff 
       + 
       + }
        Error: object 'state' not found
```

when i try to source it :source("testfunc15.R")
then i get this error :

```
      Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function"testfunc15"
```

I am saving the file in the same getwd() as other functions ,other functions are working fine.
Where am i going wrong ?
I couldn't find an answer on stackoverflow though there were many questions with the same description.
Please help

Comment: Did you want the first line to be `testfunc15 <- function(state,outcome){`

Comment: I got the same problem and my first line of code is correct I think? it's: mycustomfunction <- function (input1,input2,input3) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of your code is telling R to store the result of `testfunc15(state, outcome)` in `a`. It is not defining the function.

Also your function as written here doesn't exist. It should be, as mentionned by Dason, either :

`testfunc15 = function (state, outcome)` or `testfunc15 <- function (state, outcome)`

And the end could be `return(tempdiff)` or `tempdiff`

Comment: Thanks my bad ,,,,still a beginner in R

Comment: Hey! You gotta start somewhere :)

Comment: The return is unnecessary, a function in R return the value of the last statement, `return` is only needed if you want to exit the function prematurely (in an if clause for example).

Comment: @Tensibai really? I didn't know that. I was taught that the `return` was necessary. Thanks.

Comment: You can test it with `a<- function(x) { x*2}; b <- a(5)` and b should be 10 (on phone there may be typo)

Comment: While @Tensibai is correct, I'd argue that `return` is "necessary" for readability of the code. It's also necessary if you want to `return` a value that isn't derived from the last statement of the function. Example: `f <- function() { dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),  y = rnorm(100)); write.csv(dat, path = "some/file.csv"); return(dat) }`

Comment: @brittenb Matter of choices ;) When it's on the last line of a function it's redundant, in your example, typing `dat` is enough, calling `return` is done implicitly, needing the interpreter to find it in global namespace when it's not necessary is a waste of cpu time IMO.

Comment: @tensibai Fair enough. I've never really thought about the CPU time spent looking for `return`, but I can see how when running a function millions/billions of times, the consistent search for `return` is unnecessary.

Comment: And while at it, as the return value from `<-` is the assigned value, you can omit totally the last line in the function and end it with `tmpdff <- tempdff<-healthcareoutcome[healthcareoutcome$State==st,]` but this has few interest as it's local to the function, so just `healthcareoutcome[healthcareoutcome$State==st,]` would be enough. (and this avoid creating a copy in memory to free it just after)

Comment: What if you want to return multiple outputs? How are these captured by the calling function?